# how to download a sub directory from azure blob storage using blobxfer

Tags: linux, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using ubuntu 64bit 14.04. How can I use [blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer) to download a sub directory from Azure blob storage to my local machine . Say I have a storage account by name `MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT` ,container by name `MY_CONTAINER` and following contents inside container.

```
directory1/directory2/directory3/file1 
directory1/directory2/directory3/file2
directory1/directory2/directory3/file3
..
..
directory1/directory2/directory3/fileN
```

I want to download the sub directory `directory3` only .

I have a SAS key which has access and can download individual files however wildcards aren't working in that . My command looks like below

```
blobxfer --saskey "$MYSASKEY" MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT MY_CONTAINER "$LOCAL_DIR"  --download --remoteresource "directory1/directory2/directory3/*
```

and I am getting the following error which probably says it can't understand wildcard in the command .

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: The specified blob does not exist.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```
blobxfer --saskey "$MYSASKEY" MY_STORAGE_ACCOUNT MY_CONTAINER "$LOCAL_DIR"  --download --remoteresource . --include "directory1/directory2/directory3/*"
```

Also when you using SAS key, please make sure that `List` permission is included in SAS.

Comment: Worked for me . Thanks